# How to optimize MySQL query for counting 'userID' by joining 3 tables based on conditions? Current query is slow for large databases

Tags: mysql, join, count

I am trying to write mysql query using 3 tables and find the counts of 'userID'.

First, I have to select number of 'RefID' from **records** table between some date range,
then  select the number of 'AddressID' from **refs** table corresponds to the 'RefID',
at last find counts of 'userID'(where userID like '174%') from **addresses** based on 'AddressID' matches between **refs** and  **addresses** table.

Below is my query, the issue is that it's taking too much time and getting stuck in large database.

```
select count(DISTINCT (userID)) 
from db.addresses t 
where t.AddressID IN (
    select AddressID 
    from db.refs c 
    where c.RefID IN (
        select RefID 
        from db.records r         
        where r.StartDate >= '2022-06-30'
        and r.StartDate < '2022-07-01'
        )
    ) 
and t.userID like '174%';
```

Comment: Please add the result of the explain amd share the indexes you definwd on the underlying tables.

Comment: The source of slowness is double nesting. Rewrite your query from WHERE IN to common INNER JOIN. Then check does suitable indices exists. Or you may do this with inner subquery and rewrite outer query to WHERE EXISTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using nested subqueries, try using JOINs to combine the tables directly.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.userID) 
FROM 
    db.addresses a
JOIN 
    db.refs r ON a.AddressID = r.AddressID
JOIN 
    db.records rc ON r.RefID = rc.RefID
WHERE 
    rc.StartDate >= '2022-06-30' AND rc.StartDate < '2022-07-01'
    AND a.userID LIKE '174%';
```

Comment: thanks for the solution @Amit...working as expected. Cheers